# Build Fastcv in android studio

Tags: android, fastcv

I want to use 'fastcv' in my app with Android Studio. But the instructions all are for Eclipse in the network. How can I use 'fastcv' in Android Studio?
I use Android Studio 1.5.1

Comment: Any answer on this, I am also looking to do the same thing